# The page focus on tooltip when the tooltip open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `tooltip` just like `facebook notification`, its working correctly. Actually the the problem is that I am inserting the link of the `toolip` in the footer, when I am clicking the link the tooltip opening correctly but when I want to see the tooltip I manually take the page scroll bar to down. I want that if I click the tooltip the page focus the tooltip,  I mean the scroll bar automatically goes down when the tooltip open.

HTML:

```
<div style="margin:0 auto;width:261px">
  <ul id="nav">
    <li id="notification_li"> <a href="#" id="notificationLink">
      <h3>Title Awards</h3>
      </a>
      <div id="notificationContainer">
      <!--<div id="notificationTitle">User Achieved Titles</div>-->
      <div id="notificationsBody" class="notifications"> this is a content area in the div </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: arial
}
#nav {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #CCC;
}
#nav li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#nav li a {
    color: Blue;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav li a:hover {
    color: #00FF00;
    text-decoration: none
}
#notification_li {
    position: relative;
}
#notificationContainer {
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid rgba(100, 100, 100, .4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
    overflow: visible;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -70px;
    width: 261px;
    z-index: 2;
    display: none;
}
#notificationContainer:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    color: transparent;
    border: 10px solid black;
    border-color: transparent transparent #09F;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
#notificationTitle {
    z-index: 1000;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 8px;
    font-size: 13px;
    background-color: #09F;
    width: 245px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
#notificationsBody {
    /*padding: 33px 0px 0px 0px !important;*/
    min-height: 100px;
}
#notificationFooter {
    background-color: #e9eaed;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 8px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#notificationLink").click(function()
{
$("#notificationContainer").fadeToggle(500);
$("#notification_count").fadeOut("slow");
return false;
});

//Document Click
$(document).click(function()
{
$("#notificationContainer").hide();
});
//Popup Click
$("#notificationContainer").click(function()
{
return false
});

});
```

[The Fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/m57pgwcf/1/)

Comment: [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/m57pgwcf/2/)

Comment: Sir thanks for your response! its working but a little question from you as we setting it on the top, is this possible that we set it 400px above from bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the onclick handler add this :

```
$("body").scrollTop($("#[tooltip selector]").offset().top);
```

**Edit :** scrollTo is not working so changed it to scrollTop

Comment: Please don't call me sir.

And here is the __Fiddle :__  [Tooltip Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h7r1967r/1/)

Comment: scrollTo is not working but scrollTop is working fine.